# create a document library view on creation of new page from page layout

Tags: 2010, document-library, page-layout

I have a requirement where I need to create a new document/library or a new document library view associated with the page when I create a document library page using a custom page layout.

I'm using sharepoint 2010.

Thanks,
Lav

Comment: I was thinking of using a workflow to be associated with create page button. Being a newbee in sharepoint I'd seriously appreciate some help. :)

Comment: ok. :) You will need to use custom code to create an event receiver in Visual Studio. After you have finished coding, you can deploy the package (WSP) using Visual Studio or deploy it using PowerShell.

Comment: what do you mean by automatically associate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event receiver to listen for when a page has been created.  You attach the event receiver to the Pages library.  You can use the server object model to create a document or library.

See these links:

Creating an event receiver:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx

Creating a document library using the Server OM:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointdevelopment/thread/e01e2f60-9c2b-4298-b9c0-c3ea6d46a264

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad to help! If it answers your question, feel free to mark as answer.

Comment: Any clue on how to automatically associate the created library with the page that I'll create?

Comment: You could add a column "Library Name" in the Pages library which is updated when you create the new library.